# What kind of visa does a citizen of the Philippines need for Guadeloupe?

Tags: visas, filipino-citizens, guadeloupe

I am a citizen of the Philippines and would like to enter Guadeloupe for tourism. What kind of a visa do I need?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: What is your citizenship? What is the purpose of your visit? Without that information, we can't possibly answer. And did you try Googling for "Guadeloupe visa"? It's always better to rely on official sources of information.

Comment: I am a filipina and I will go to Guadeloupe for tourist. BTW thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Guadeloupe is an Overseas Department of France. You can check the current entry requirements on the website of the French Ministry of Foreign Affairs https://france-visas.gouv.fr/web/france-visas

Note that you need a visa that's valid for Guadeloupe. A visa for mainland France (Schengen visa) is not valid to enter Guadeloupe and other French overseas departments and territories.